# Singleton Pattern - Cannot call member function without object

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, singleton, member

I'm new to singletons and generally to OOP, and i have a little problem with my code. I searched here for "Cannot call member function without object", but the engine returned some topics that aren't related to singletons. 
This is my code and the compiler tells me "cannot call member function 'void mySingleton::set_value(int)' without object". Do you have any ideas on how could i solve this?

```
#include <iostream>

class mySingleton{

private:
        int value;
        static mySingleton *_pInstance;
        mySingleton(int Value=0) {value=Value;}
public:
    ~mySingleton() {value=0;}

    static mySingleton *getInstance()
    {
        if(!_pInstance) _pInstance=new mySingleton;
        return _pInstance;
    }

    int  get_value()        {return value;}
    void set_value(int x=0) {value=x;}

};

mySingleton *mySingleton::_pInstance=NULL;

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Initial value:" << mySingleton::getInstance()->get_value() << std::endl;
    mySingleton::set_value(5);
    std::cout << "Modified value: " << mySingleton::getInstance()->get_value() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Call it the same way you're calling `get_value()`.

Comment: Thanks, this works! But if i want to declare one or two objects of this type? I know that they would point to the same adress, but typing "mySingleton *a1; a1 = new mySingleton;" won't work.

Comment: `want to declare one or two objects of this type?` If there could be more than exactly one object of this type, then it wouldn't be much of a **Single**ton, now would it?

Comment: I think that i didn't make myself clear. When i said "i want to declare one or two objects of this type" i wanted to say that i would like to create two references to the singleton. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: `mySingleton* a1 = mySingleton::getInstance(); mySingleton* a2 = a1;` Feel free to make as many copies of the pointer as your heart desires.